# Postfix mail server refuses connections from outside mail servers

Tags: postfix, smtp

I have a Postfix server with SMTP listening on port 587 which cannot be reached by outside mail servers like Gmail and hence I receive this Mail Delivery Failure when sending an email from GMail to useraccount@mydomain.tld:

The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7720
[mail.mydomain.tld MailServerIP:**(It is interesting that there is no port here!)** socket error]

```
----- Original message -----

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=mime-version:in-reply-to:references:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
        bh=pEP+FUpQu4YrUIJfRtRY72qvieH+prFPrjpP+XncC+A=;
        b=xWURH+CuLyCB2dCkDZTmlncHMmvAaP24KwgoqUxur1FxRye7cJ4qAHYDjEQLGoecJO
         U3ka/qkBSwcDnCsrBZc+I4YL7sN6pRJvBatv/EXbYdwoczq8LoizXWuYKxprCgSiVKu5
         3eFdaFN8dCBXJncp4mMMOzKwonqe1fO+zuV5fI3ef7TCgThEBiCwZrEFUlPb64MCkQzY
         wKu/gwKVS5yvO2MvD3IJQJeqmaj2kegC9zIIQo5w9w/HeS4wasyVU9bIAAuCG9azdiL6
         wR9CzV95xHJYWv/3YUcB0CBMuL7vrelDlVlRddhrhJRV4jkzOHOYlgvDVhd0GPj7/Mib
         KqOg==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20130820;
        h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:in-reply-to:references:from:date
         :message-id:subject:to;
        bh=pEP+FUpQu4YrUIJfRtRY72qvieH+prFPrjpP+XncC+A=;
        b=lSA5HbBTMeKoIOp7/ZuktmhmO67v/oN4gAlk6kJDlPj2ue9yCDx8s0IdBlF4QENiae
         HQqug+EqwxQItawgwYO8ZGmQDs1nPPjxLJdymIGHCdIF4G149fk0GSkbE3+yhwvGvTXj
         JPYFZpDeQvnLBy293t2lIkxk5GGvaC2w7gZvP3Pt6qZAFZvbVxGTOoKwqp+zJ7valQhr
         xvmImfSJAw2fzIzTXE4Or4XXsPXpP5i1rcmRwDwGk8qQnXoCVfZLoyaQBPq2J5ChWPR0
         w5nLlVSVB7IFfwmRZEfVwVxjOvHCMbXtu1Eeyl1JZ88vfD0OvbSeWn7RwBSoLWZoOiVl
         EuYg==
X-Gm-Message-State: AD7BkJJ4ZaGY+7wGDmRTWxi4nvS2OwcKWPrcxB9LMV0I1cD9DTnaAiMAC+1nFhQx0/W8no4EPXCNk7rU7gk8Eg==
X-Received: by 10.28.44.9 with SMTP id s9mr11997524wms.96.1459775140100; Mon,
 04 Apr 2016 06:05:40 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.28.53.66 with HTTP; Mon, 4 Apr 2016 06:05:00 -0700 (PDT)
In-Reply-To: <8b4794cab4431ff4cc910761b74fb544@mydomain.tld>
References: <8b4794cab4431ff4cc910761b74fb544@mydomain.tld>
From: Name Family <gmailAccount@gmail.com>
Date: Mon, 4 Apr 2016 17:35:00 +0430
Message-ID: <CAB4H0ddCYD=FfL4JsZSoqJtsmNKew+v_5KFpKfCeeOb7GD6fxQ@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Re: test
To: Name <useraccount@mydomain.tld>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a113d9e02ad7f4f052fa86217
```

Also, digging from an external ISP to check DNS records results:

`dig MX mydomain.tld`:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.tld.       21599   IN  MX  10 mail.mydomain.tld.
```

And then, `dig A mail.mydomain.tld` results:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mail.mydomain.tld.  21599   IN  A   proper.ip.address
```

I have been able to send and receive email within the mail server between local accounts and also send to outside mail server like GMail, but I cannot receive from outside.

my postfix config is:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no
# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_un$
myhostname = mydomain.tld
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mydomain.tld, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +

inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
```

Master.cf content:

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
587      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

netstat -tulpn:

```
    Active Internet connections (only servers)
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8888            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2050/stunnel4   
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21976           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      877/sshd        
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      907/named       
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:51101         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2310/irssi      
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:51102         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2292/rtorrent   
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:51103           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2292/rtorrent   
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      879/dovecot     
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:51106           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2324/python     
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:51107           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2317/python     
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      879/dovecot     
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      963/mysqld      
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1194            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1027/openvpn    
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11162/master    
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      879/dovecot     
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      879/dovecot     
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2224/perl       
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4433            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2317/python     
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21201           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      656/vsftpd
```

iptables -L:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:submission

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:smtp ctstate ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:submission
```

can anybody help me please?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you telnet to your server? Try from inside and outside. Try on port 587 and 25.

Comment: @CharlieWilson telnet can be performed to port 587 from inside, but not outside

Comment: you didn't specify your telnet results for port 25. I'd open port 25 and see if Gmail can now connect to your postfix server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Postfix installation is undoubtedly configured to send and receive e-mail for local users only. In order to receive messages from the Internet, Postfix must be able to receive connections on ports 25/tcp (SMTP) and 465/tcp (SMTP over SSL). I'm not sure if GMail initially tries to establish a secure SMTP connection (465/tcp), but GMail certainly uses the port 587/tcp (SUBMISSION) to receive messages from end users only. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796530/what-is-the-difference-between-ports-465-and-587) for an overview of the difference between these ports.

I guess executing `dpkg-reconfigure --priority=low postfix` and supplying [proper answers to the wizard](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix#Configuration) will allow Postfix to receive messages from the Internet. Or else:

1. Set `inet_interfaces = all` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

   ```
   inet_interfaces = all
   ```
2. In `/etc/postfix/master.cf`, comment the `587` service and uncomment `smtp`, `smtpd`, `submission` and `smtps` services:

   ```
   # 587      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
   smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
   smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
   submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
     -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
     -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
     -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
     -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
   #  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
   #  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
   #  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
   #  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
     -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
   #  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
   smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
     -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
     -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
     -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
     -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
   #  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
   #  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
   #  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
   #  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
   #  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
   #  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
   ```

Use an external diagnostic tool to check if your mail server is publicly acessible on ports 25/tcp, 465/tcp and 587/tcp. I suggest you to use http://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx and http://dns.kify.com/ .

Comment: This post solved days of frustration for me. Eventually I realized that my residential ISP service doesn't allow traffic on any of these 3 ports which is why I could never get my GMail to be sent to my local mail server.